# Probability $\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n+1} {M \choose m+1}{M-m-1 \choose j-m-1}/{N \choose j} $

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have a prob. problem:

A school has $N$ students in which $M$ students are leader (of each class in school), and $N>M$.
There are $2n+1$ balls in the black box including $n+1$ blue balls and $n$ red balls (where $2n+1<M$).

The balls are randomly distributed to students in the school such that one student get only one (blue or red) ball.

1/ Given value $m$ ($m\le n$), what is the probability  $P_1$  that $M$ leaders take $m+1$ blue balls and at most $m$ red ones?

2/ What is the probability $P_2$ that $M$ leaders take the number of blue balls greater than red ones?

I already computed $P_1=\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n+1} {M \choose m+1}{M-m-1 \choose j-m-1}/{N \choose j} $ but not sure it's correct.
but not $P2$.

Can anyone help me to find out $P_1$? and also $P_2$? And could you give the simplification  and upper bound of them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think P1should be $P1 = \binom{M}{m+1}\sum ^m_{j=0} \binom{M-m-1}{j}$

$P2 = \sum ^n _{i=1} \binom{M}{i} \sum _{j=0} ^{j \lt i} \binom {M-i}{j}$

Comment: in your case $P1$ and $P2$ are $>1$?

Comment: Those aren't probabilities, they are counts of events.  Specifically this attempt at $P1$ is only the count of ways to distribute $m+1$ blue balls and up to $m$ red balls among the $M$ leaders.  It doesn't include the ways to distribute the remaining balls among the rest of the students. Nor does it divide by the total space.

Comment: no, the problem is that the balls are distributed to all students, then we have to find the probability M leaders take $m+1$ blue balls and up to $m$ red balls.

Comment: They are not probabilities. My mistake. They are counts.